# PHP: mysql return value "escapes" textarea

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

If the return value of a mysql query contains `""` and `/` the content is displayed outside the textarea

```
content = <a href="url">link</a>
```

`echo()` is used inside the textarea

```
<textarea><?php echo $row['value']; ?></textarea>
```

the textarea displays `<a href=` and what follows it is displayed outside the textarea

How do I contain all html inside the textarea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
htmlspecialchars($row['value'])
```

Comment: @dany: Note you must use `htmlspecialchars()` *every* time you put text into HTML elements and attribute values, not just in `<textarea>`. If you allow untrusted content into your HTML without escaping you're going to get cross-site-scripting security holes.